# Binary Search average time complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, searching

I'm looking for explanations for this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoGjC.png).

I have tried and found the solution in book Art of Computer Programming. Volume 3. Sorting and Searching. Second Edition but this didn't help me at all. Is there anybody to explain it in easier way for me.

Comment: Did you actually get that expression from the book mentioned in your post, or somewhere else?

Comment: @DanielV This expression i got from en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm and it is in Performance.

Comment: "Since binary search is the optimal algorithm for searching with comparisons" a little off topic but that made me laugh.  It is well known that higher arity searches are vastly superior on modern computer architectures.  Anyway, your question could be improved by explaining what part of the wikipedia explanation you didn't understand.

Comment: @DanielV I would like to know how to exacly get the forumula for average time complexity step by step from where are comming the variables in this forumula. I found on wikipedia in Performace section formula for I(n) but I don't understand where that come from. I tried calculating sum but I didn't end up with the same result.